# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer una lista de objetos desde un índice hasta otro (No entera) por ejemplo desde la posición dos a la 4 en c#?

Tags: c#, lista, arraylist, object, objeto

Estoy realizando un programa y necesito recorrer una lista desde distintas posiciones hasta otras, no recorrerla entera, pero no se como hacerlo.

Por ejemplo tengo una lista de 74 miembros y quiero recorrerla desde la posición 0 hasta la 14, de la 15 a la 29 y así...

Muchas gracias

Comment: Porque querrias recorrer solo una parte? estas seguro de lo que buscas estara en ese rango?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿No te vale con pedir a una lista que te de los valores de una posición concreta?

```
var numeros = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

for (int i = 3; i != 9; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine($"El número en la posición {i} es {numeros[i]}.");
```

El código anterior muestra los datos de la lista desde la posición tres a la ocho. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LSgNBEDzPfEUZPOyScUHjK6zxEsRLBMGDh5DDMLZLw@6MTk8isuxXefOaD1sn4EE8NdVV3VXl5MSFSOO4FfYNnj4lUVfrv6hasX//t1qGtiWXOHip7slTZFdr7VorgscYmmg79FpJsokddoFf8GDZF5Ji/rLewMZGyoNE7WyE33YUg2ABTx9YsaQb9um2PzU4M5gZnBtcGFwaXBlcG8wxZDulXkNEkZXgfDqr8zhaYF5jOuUy02qZ84WWqufIiXINKo4ndy38/vvgB/JoLd6CsOP9l0fPA0jQ/8ZZ82aoJmWt1aCHcfwB)</kbd>.